# Fitting a Gaussian to a dataset using geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm pretty new to R and am trying to analyse some data and fit a Gaussian to it using the ggplot2 package.

I am able to plot a smooth curve using geom_smooth and the results are as expected. However, using geom_density (see code below) the result is not as expected.

```
ggplot(All_Wavelengths_LabVIEW_selected_)+    
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(Actual_Wavelength, B), se = FALSE)+
  geom_density(kernel = "gaussian", Actual_Wavelength, B)
```

Instead of a Gaussian fit, I get: 
'Error in fortify(data) : object 'B' not found'

I don't understand how this can occur given it uses B to plot the smooth curve without any issue.

In addition, I would like to do the following:

1. Extract FWHM value of the peak
2. Overlay multiple of these Gaussian fits for other sets of data (similar to B) with the same X axis

Is this possible?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Consider making your question reproducible. Include a sample of your code and describe some of the fields in the underlying data. It's hard to help without knowing exactly what the data look like!

Comment: Is `All_Wavelengths_LabVIEW_selected_` a data.frame? If so, is there a column called `B` in it? If B is a vector outside of the data.frame, its better to move it in to your data set so that ggplot knows where to find it.

Comment: Yes its a data frame - all the columns in it are letters B:Q for simplicity (except the first which is 'Actual_Wavelength'

Comment: I should also say, the column contents are all numeric